# Problem viewing Turtlebot in Rviz

Tags: rviz, urdf, turtlebot, xtion

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm following the turtlebot tutorials and I'm at the 3D visualization part.

So i've SSH'd into the Turtlebot and run the following,

Bring up the turtlebot (GOOD)
roslaunch turtlebot_bringup minimal.launch

Start vision system (GOOD)
roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch (instead of roslaunch turtlebot_bringup 3dsensor.launch )

Visualize turtlebot in Rviz (PROBLEM)
roslaunch turtlebot_rviz_launchers view_robot.launch

Rviz shows up and there is a white blob robot model instead of my turtlebot 2. I can't see the point cloud even though my asus xtion is definitely running and even though the URDF is parsed OK, the robot is not showing up and every robotpart of the model has a red error. A screenshot of Rviz is below

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1yulGt-BPu-dFBDSlhobVJYQ2c/edit?usp=sharing

How do i show the point cloud in rviz and my turtlebot 2 model properly?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/71440/problem-viewing-turtlebot-in-rviz/) by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on ROS Answers with karma: 236 on 2013-08-06

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2013-08-06**:
Can we see your tf graph. Usually, this result is due to a no publication of tf. Please make sure you have the node robot_state_publisher active.

**Comment by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) on 2013-08-06**:
ok, the output of rosrun tf view_graph as a pdf is here

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B1yulGt-BPu-OTZDSXdybkVibzg/edit?usp=sharing

Did rosnode list, robot state publisher is running.

Any ideas?

**Comment by [jep31](https://answers.ros.org/users/2564/jep31/) on 2013-08-06**:
your tf graph is really incomplete. You should have all the robot tf and more tf even for vision system.
Maybe robot state publisher doesn't publish topic because it doesn't receive joint_state.
Are you using two computer ? And what happens when you first use $rosnode list before running bringup ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

fixed it randomly by using the default turtlebot 3dsensor.launch instead of openni.launch

---

Originally posted by [llSourcell](https://answers.ros.org/users/4668/llsourcell/) with karma: 236 on 2013-08-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0